# Substring a string until first number character in Java

Tags: java

how can i extract a string until he's first number character?
For example i have this string and i want to cut them from the start until the first nummeric ( 1 or 12).
The text is dynamic so only the start word is every time the same not the number and not the position of the number.

> geschäftsführerin anna maier tannenstraße 12 landau

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the

> public String[] split(String regex)

method in String class, just need to pass a regex pattern with numbers like [0-9].

```
String getSubstringUntilFirstNumber(String source) {
    return source.split("[0-9]")[0];
}
```